# Visualize the percentage of different values of a categorial column within different bins of a numerical column

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns `col1` and `class`. `class` is binary. I want to plot a histogram and visualize the percentage of each one of `class` values on different bins of `col1` column. Here are my attempts:

1- Two histograms, one for each value of `class` column:

```
df.col1[df.class == 0].hist()
```

[image]

```
df.col1[df.class == 1].hist()
```

[image]

2- Put them all (two values of class) together in one chart

```
df.groupby('class').col1.hist(alpha=0.9)
```

[image]

As you can see from the first two graphs, those rows with `class==1` are rare comparing to another `class==0` and when we put them together (third graph), we don't see their effect (look at those tiny orange areas in the chart). One solution is using the percentage of each value of `class` within each bin. I tried this one:

```
df.groupby('class').col1.transform(lambda x: x/sum(x)).hist(alpha=0.9)
```

[image]

and apparently didn't work. I'm looking for a way to visualize the percentage of each class value within different bins.

Comment: A better visualization than trying to combine the marginals would probably be the joint distribution between `col1` and `class`. With seaborn, you can do `sns.jointplot(x="col1", y="class", data=df)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of items per class is highly unbalanced, there is no way to have both plots in the same y-axes for histograms, If both clases have similar distribution among the values you can use [`distplots`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) to perform some normalization on the data:

```
uniques = df['class'].unique()
targets = [df.col1[df['class'] == val] for val in uniques]

for target in targets:
    sns.distplot(target, rug=True)
```